# Using sshpass, how to work on the logged in server

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I'm new for shell script. I've tried to login on server by `sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM` command and I'm successfully logged in.

And my question is how can I work (pass more commands) further on the same logged in server?

Comment: Passing passwords as commandline arguments is generally not a good idea. Why don't you use public SSH keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh allows to run commands on remote

> ssh user@server "command"

sshpass actually runs ssh just inserting password for you. So you can call command as you do by ssh

> sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
>   YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM "command ; bash"

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried the way you suggested, but it didn't work. I couldn't login to my specified server when I added the command.  'sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM "cd /home/abc/xyz"'.

Comment: When you supply command to ssh, it run that command and exit. If you want to run further command and stay logged in, you need to call bash at the end of your commands and -t option if you want to stay logged in. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment to Ibrahim, when you are running command "cd /home/abc/xyz", it will only run for the particular bash session which got created by the remote connection you made via ssh command. 
if you want to run command remotely, you should use below command to fulfill your requirement.

```
ssh YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM "command"
```

if you want to run more commands at a time, use && between your commands.
Example could be as below

```
ssh YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM "command1 && command2 && command3"
```

Read about && and || on Internet for more information about same.

Comment: Hi @Nitesh, thanks for your response, I tried ' ssh YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM "cd /home/abc/xyz" '. But it still couldn't reach to the given path, but it did not stop me from login to my server. Is there any possibility that I might be doing it wrong.